# How to check if the user hits enter with no input in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script where I want the user to input a value and the script returns a randomized string for a password.  If they just hit enter when prompted for the length of the password, I want it to be a default of 9 characters.

How do I handle no input?

I tried something like this, but don't think it is quite right:

Write-Host Enter the password length requirement:

```
$length = Read-Host
IF ( $length -eq $NULL) 
    { Do continue on with the value of 9 for the length}
ELSE
    {Use $length for the rest of the script}
```

The else portion works just fine; however when generating passwords I keep finding myself typing 9 over and over again.  I'd rather just hit enter.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

PowerShell is great, because you can shorten code very often and it works :)

```
if (!$length) { 
  Do continue on with the value of 9 for the length
} ...
```

Why?

```
[bool]$null         # False
[bool]''            # False
[bool]'something'   # True
```

Comment: In the if block, set $Length to 9 and then you are good to go.

Comment: @jason I wanted to show only the condition, I guess John is capable to do the rest :) Anyway, thx for reviewing.

Comment: John may not have realized that, I like to be explicit some times.  :)

Answer (score 5):

I would say "works as designed". Because $lenght is not NULL. the right test is :

```
if ($length -eq [string]::empty)
```

So perhaps a conjunction of the two tests.

JP

Answer (score 2):

IF ( $length -eq "")

instead of 
   IF ( $length -eq $NULL)

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute best way to do this would be to it a parameter to the script and use the V2 validation attributes.  This will also prevent them putting in bad data, like strings

param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateRange(1,9)]
[Int]
$Length
)

This will give you better validation and consistent and localized errors.

Hope this helps